# Apple Receipt Validation

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I am doing the application with `Non renewable subscriptions`. I am receiving the `Status code 21007`, while validating the Receipt , what should i do after receiving that status?

Thanks advance

Answer (score 0):

21007
This receipt is from the test environment, but it was sent to the production environment for verification. Send it to the test environment instead.

Check this page [AppStore receipt validation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html)